# Setting up Emacs24 for python development

Tags: python, emacs, emacs24

I want to configure Emacs24 for python development. So far I've fallowed the instructions in [this blog post](http://www.yilmazhuseyin.com/blog/dev/emacs-setup-python-development/) and done all the steps successfully, but nothing happened when I reopened Emacs. It's maybe because the blog post is a little out of date (May 2011) and it has been tested on Emacs23. does anybody have any better instructions? preferably tested recently on Emacs24.

What I need most is auto-complete for python (version >3), and django after that.

By the way I'm using LinuxMint14 if it is any important.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably best to install things from one of the repositories. `pymacs` and `pyflakes` are both in MELPA. This repo also has the `flymake-python-pyflakes` - which is kind of an extension of the snippet in the blog post.

You will probably have very little use for `ropemacs` at first because that's not intended for Python development proper, it's for extending Emacs with Python (rather than Emacs Lisp).

So, I'd say, first add this:

```
(add-to-list 'package-archives
    '("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/") t)
(add-to-list 'package-archives 
    '("marmalade" . "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/"))
(package-initialize)
```

to your Emacs init file (usually `~/.emacs`), evaluate it with <kbd>M-x</kbd>`eval-buffer`. Then <kbd>M-x</kbd>`list-packages`, search for Pymacs, pyflakes, auto-complete and whatever you like. Pressing <kbd>RET</kbd> on package name will open a buffer with package description. Pressing <kbd>i</kbd> on package name will schedule it for installation, pressing <kbd>x</kbd> will install all packages scheduled for installation.

Also note that ropes is a Python library needed for many code-related tasks in various editors. So you'd need to install that too, sooner or later. Usually, if you have Python installed, you'd already have `pip` program, so I'd suggest you do:

```
$ pip install rope ropemacs
```

It will be probably:

```
$ pip3 install rope_py3k
```

(I'm guessing from the package name).

Rather than installing it by hand. If `pip` isn't installed by default:

```
$ sudo apt-get install pip
```

(it could be also named `python-pip`, at least this is the name on RHEL distros). Also on RHEL there are two different versions, `python-pip` and `python-pip3`, the other one being for Python 3.X I believe, so install whichever is appropriate.

The benefit of using an installer of this kind is that it will do all the maintenance job in the way that others can anticipate, and so would be able to help if need be.

There are also lots of Python-related bits of Emacs Lisp code floating around. I'd suggest you check out https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/elpy/wiki (installable through MELPA). MELPA also lists PyDE support: http://pyde.bitbucket.org/ but I don't know what it is.

Comment: thank you. that's very helpful. because usually a little mistake can ruin it all when you do all the job by hand. specially the elpy package. I think that would solve the problem. btw have you tried these yourself?

Comment: @VahidM I think I took the hard path when I started, I did install things by hand, failing some times to do it due to different factors :) I do, certainly, use some of the mentioned above, specifically, `pip` - that's sure, `pymacs`, `rope`, `pyflakes` - too. But my Python coding is mostly about writing maintenance scripts, so I rarely get the chance to test the advertised features of `elpy`. Also, some times creating a rope project seems like too much for the task, but, again, I don't do that much of Python development.